# mediaelement.js sync volume in multiple videos

Tags: jquery, video, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I have a series of pages that are each displaying a collection of videos. A sort of video playlist, if you will. To make it easy to address each of the videos, I run the mediaelement.js plug-in on them and store the mediaElement object in an array like this:

```
var mediaArray = [];
$(".class").each(function (index) {
    $(this).mediaelementplayer({
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
            mediaArray[index] = mediaElement;
        }
    });
});
```

This works great for allowing me to have controls outside of the mediaelement.js player address the various mediaElement objects. So I can, for example, have users click on the title of the next video to switch to playing that one.

Where I run into trouble is when I try to allow the user to change the volume on one of the videos and then maintain that volume when they start playing the next video.

I can easily write a function like this:

```
    setAllVolume = function (value) {
        for (var i=0, il=mediaArray.length; i<il; i++) {
            mediaArray[i].setVolume(value);
        }
    }
```

And that works great if I have a volume control outside of the mediaelement.js controls. (E.g., if I build a jQueryUI slider for a universal volume control.)

What I've tried is to add an event listener for the "changevolume" event and have that fire my `setAllVolume` function like this:

```
$(".class").each(function (index) {
    $(this).mediaelementplayer({
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
            mediaArray[index] = mediaElement;
            mediaElement.addEventListener("volumechange", function () {
                setAllVolume(mediaElement.volume);
            });
});
```

As you might imagine, setting the volume in this fashion causes each mediaElement to fire its own "volumechange" event and to recursively call the `setAllVolume` function in a cascading fail pile that causes one's browser to hang up as it churns through the process again and again.

So, is there a way I can have a change in the volume of one video reflected in the other videos without running into this recursion? (I should mention that I'm using H.264 video and this problem appears to only occur in browsers using the Flash plug-in to play that format.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the quickest solution to my issue is going to be to run a check on the current volume of the mediaElement stored as I loop through my array:

```
setAllVolume = function (value) {
    for (var i=0, il=mediaArray.length; i<il; i++) {
        if (mediaArray[i].volume !== value) {
            mediaArray[i].setVolume(value);
        }
    }
}
```